# Why while loop in plsql not working?

Tags: oracle, plsql, while-loop

Noob question, why this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_tipo_aula ( nm IN VARCHAR2, n IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
type array_t is varray(3) of varchar2(11);
array array_t := array_t('Conferenze','Laboratorio','Aula');
Aula varchar2(11);
i NUMBER;
BEGIN
i:=1;
SELECT tipo_modulo
INTO Aula
FROM Modulo
WHERE Nome_modulo = nm;
--
WHILE Aula <> array_t(i)
LOOP
i := i+1;
END LOOP;
RETURN array_t(1 + mod(i+n-1,3));
END;
/
```

is giving me those errors :

```
15/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
15/12    PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '!='
19/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
19/8     PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

knowing that the first select has the purpouse of loading into aula a string of the same value of the array above ? My desired result is to obtain from the while the index of first occurrence in the array of the string contained in Aula and then return the value of the array shifted of some position.

Ex :

input value ... , 2

selection result Aula

Expected result of the while : i = 3

Expected returned value : array_t(1+mod(3+2-1,3)) = array_t(2) = 'Laboratorio')

I don't know what kind of syntax mistake I'm doing honestly.

Comment: `array_t` is a type name, not a variable name.

Comment: if the error says "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '!='" then where is the != in your code?

Comment: yes it does   @kevinsky

Comment: @kevinsky, in oracle `<>` is the same as `!=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple typo.  You need to use the *variable name* in your code, not the type.  So, correct these two lines ...

```
WHILE Aula <> array(i)
....
RETURN array(1 + mod(i+n-1,3));
```

... and your code will compile.

---

By the way, `array` is a really poor name for a variable because it is so easy to confuse with a data type.  Even with toy code it pays to use clear names.  Even `l_array` would be an improvement.